# What hook language should I use for local pre-commit hooks written in Python?

Tags: python, pre-commit.com

I’m working on a [local pre-commit hook](https://pre-commit.com/#repository-local-hooks) written in Python. At first, I saw [this quote from the pre-commit documentation](https://pre-commit.com/#python):

> #### python
>
> The hook repository must be installable via `pip install .` (usually by either `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`).

I made the repo with the local hook installable using `pip install .`, but later found out that [that isn’t supposed to work with local hooks](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1926).

More recently, I created a bare-bones [`.pre-commit-config.yaml`](https://pre-commit.com/#adding-pre-commit-plugins-to-your-project) that looks like this:

```yaml
repos:
    -
        repo: local
        hooks:
            -
                id: &id1 test1
                name: *id1
                language: python
                entry: python -c "print('Hello, world!')"
                always_run: true
            -
                id: &id2 test2
                name: *id2
                language: system
                entry: python -c "print('Hello, world!')"
                always_run: true
```

Both seem to do the same thing.

Here’s my question: for local hooks, is there any difference between using [the `python` `language`](https://pre-commit.com/#python) and [the `system` `language`](https://pre-commit.com/#system)? Should I prefer one over the other when writing hooks in Python? I would think that `system` hooks would rely on the user’s `PATH` (and that `python` hooks might not), but the `python` command isn’t on my `PATH` normally, and the hook still works (I start a [`nix-shell`](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/unstable/command-ref/nix-shell.html) when I want to run `python`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`repo: local` hooks do not "install" anything beyond `additional_dependencies`: https://pre-commit.com/#repository-local-hooks

a `language: system` hook cannot install anything -- it is the escape hatch for unsupported things where it is on the *user* to make sure their environment is provisioned correctly

a `language: python` hook will set up a virtualenv and install things.  in the case of `repo: local` this would just be `additional_dependencies`

~generally `language: python` is more portable (the point of pre-commit is it installs and manages the tools so your contributors don't need a big complicated setup script).  and even without dependencies it's slightly more portable because `python` will be available for use in `entry` on all the platforms via `virtualenv`

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit